# certificate is invalid for Net Core 3.1 running under macos

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, .net-core

I have a net core 3.1 app trying to call an HTTPS endpoint. This HTTPS endpoint uses a self-signed certificate which I have the CA certificate installed in my machine under `/etc/ssl/cert/pem`, I tried call it via `curl` and worked.

Well, in my coworker's machine (windows) it works normally, but in my MacOS Monterey:

```
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Well, I tried some things but nothing worked:

1. added this env variable `"SSL_CERT_DIR" : "/etc/ssl"`
2. added this env variable `"SSL_CERT_FILE": "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"`

I don't want to change anything in the code because it works normally on other machines (not macos). I'm pretty sure that this error happens because for some reason the .Net Core is note using my CA cert somehow.

Any tips here?

Comment: Where .NET Core app is running that is using self signed certificate? On MAC OS, is this app working with curl but not working from browser? Is it the case?

Comment: Yes, exactly this. Working in MAC OS, when I try with `dotnet run` it does not work, but via `curl` it works.

Comment: 1) Have you added this cert on macos Keychain Access? 2) Does cert Common Name matches the URL you are accessing?

Comment: yes for both questions :D , otherwise it won't work using CURL.